# How to automatically adjust all pieces of a voice to a certain decibel in adobe audition?

Tags: adobe-audition

When I record my voice it appears like this:
[image: before edit]

Then I have to modify it piecemeal and after a hard work it appears like this (Still full of under_line and out_of_line areas).
[image: after modification]

How can I record my voice like below image?
Or
How can I automatically adjust all pieces of sound to -3 decibel line at once?
[image: desired]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way to approach this is to use a fairly standard audio processing toolchain which contains a compressor and limiter.

The toolchain will normally sit like this:

> EQ >> DYNAMICS >> LIMITER

The limiter will be the last piece of the puzzle in the chain that can ensure that your peaks do not exceed -3dBFS.

Comment: Thanks for your hardware solution but do you mean there is no software solution like a magical wizard or scripting some actions or etc?

Comment: Pretty much all audio software will contain a compressor & limiter. Refer to the manual if you can't find it.

Comment: @mitra - that solution is available as software and hardware. Whatever audio workstation you use will have these.